# Can you hibernate/reboot in Linux instead of hibernate/poweroff?

Tags: linux, power-management, hibernate

I'm using pm-hibernate, and would like to reboot the machine after it's done hibernating, rather than having the machine turn off.

Is there a way to do this with pm-hibernate, or any other Linux hibernate thing?

Comment: I would think the answer is, probably, yes, but I don't know how. You'll probably you'll probably have to investigate all the steps that make hibernate in the first place and write a script to do it. Because I think this is all basically scripted in the first place.

Comment: But I just want to know why you want to reboot the system after hibernate. AFAIK, boot up the box after hibernate will bring you to the stats you turned it off. You want to loop it over? Sorry for my poor English. I hope I expressed my idea fully.

Comment: Dual boot, if you hibernate windows you can reboot quickly into an already hibernated linux. Or the other way around. :)

Comment: Seven years later, we have UEFI, which makes that quick-OS-change trick all the more attractive (`efibootmgr --bootnext $windowsbootid && $hibernatecommand`).  Shame there's no way to set BootNext from Windows, really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man pm-hibernate` in the "CONFIGURATION VARIABLES" section:

> HIBERNATE_MODE
>              Default method to power down the system when hibernating. If not
>              set, the system will use the kernel default as a default value.
>              Check /sys/power/disk for valid values. The default value will be
>              surrounded by [square brackets].

On my system that file contains:

```
test testproc [shutdown] reboot
```

Set the value by placing a file in `/etc/pm/config.d/`. For example, you could create a file called `/etc/pm/config.d/hibernate` and in it put the line:

```
HIBERNATE_MODE=reboot
```