# Windows 7 - Reboot after hibernating

Tags: windows-7, macos, hibernate, boot-camp

Similar situation to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/288317/how-can-i-convince-windows-7-to-reboot-upon-hibernating-rather-than-powering-dow). But I have a bit of a different situation. I have a Mac and have Windows 7 in BootCamp. I frequently hibernate and restart manually to keep my Windows state and use macOS. With VNC servers on both, I frequently use both OSes remotely. However I can't switch from Windows back to Mac if I want to hibernate Windows and not reboot it. I do have a script that shuts down Mac and reboots into Windows, though.

Is there a way to automate the Hibernate -> reboot into Mac process?

Comment: It is risky to use an alternate OS on a computer while another is in hibernation. This can only be done safely if the operating systems are totally isolated from each other with no shared drives. Otherwise data loss or corruption is likely. The answer by Mahmoud in the question linked to explains the situation more fully. The problem is inherent in the way hibernation works.

Comment: @LMiller7 yes in normal circumstances I would agree. However because OS X has read only access to the bootcamp partition, what Mahmoud explained in the other question is not applicable here. Likewise, Windows only has read-only access to Mac. So while they aren't technically isolated, they are prevented from doing any damage to each other. Thus, this is a safe thing to do. On top of that, I've been doing it for years and have had no ill effects.